# parametric solution to system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the system of equations

```
5x -4y +2z = 11
2x -3y +5z = 3
```

in a matrix it looks like

```
5    -4    2     11
2    -3    5     3
```

I flipped the rows and made the pivot 1

```
2    -3    5     3         1/2r1
5    -4    2     11
```

made the 5 under the 1 to 0

```
1    -3/2  5/2   3/2
5    -4    2     11       r2 - 5r1
```

```
1   -3/2     5/2      3/2
0    7/2    -21/2     7/2
```

so I have

```
1x -3/2y  + 5/2z   = 3/2
    7/2y  + -21/2z = 7/2
z = t
```

is this correct? choosing a number for z will give the solution for y, which can be put into the top equation to find the solution for x

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct - but do not choose a value for z. Keep a parameter.  The set of solutions is infinite, geometrically it gives a straight line. For any choice of parameter you get only one point from this line.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the first equation by $-5$ and the second by $2$ and adding both we get
$$-21x+14y=-49$$ so $$x=\frac{49}{21}+\frac{14}{21}y$$ defining $$y=21t$$
we get
$$x=\frac{49}{21}+14t$$,y=21t$$